# CardDAV Sync Protocol Support for iOS

Tags: iphone, carddav

How do I support CardDAV Sync protocol programmatically in iPhone? The default addressbook iPhone API does not seem to return the contacts synced via CardDAV protocol (for ex: gmail contacts)